# Какие способы хранения данных есть в QT?

Tags: база-данных, qt, хранение-данных

У меня в приложение есть таблица с данными и нужно сохранить информацию при выходе из приложения. Как эффективнее хранить данные в Qt? Я раньше не делал подобных приложений на Qt. Подскажите каком класс за это отвечает?
Заранеее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вашу таблицу поместить в БД SQLite. Начать изучать можно [сдесь](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-programming.html).